# USB-creator: Error erasing device: Unknown or unsupported erase type

Tags: usb, system-installation, live-usb

I created a live usb using usb-creator-gtk. I installed Ubuntu with it and all was good with the world. Now I am trying to use the same memory stick and create a live USB for 14.04 and I get the following error when trying to erase the disk.

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.gi._glib.GError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
  retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper", line 239, in Format
  block.call_format_sync('dos', GLib.Variant('a{sv}', {'erase': GLib.Variant('s',   '')}), None)
gi._glib.GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error erasing device: Unknown or unsupported erase type `'
```

How can I fix this so I can create a new live USB?

Answer (score 7):

SB must be formatted to FAT32. then it'll work again. I was creating the live USB stick fo rubuntu 14.04. when I encountered it and  now its working fine

Comment: yes, it works. but i think this is not the real solution. the usb creator should work in any format, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

First, use the gparted to create one partition on the usb with a fat32 file system on it. Then  go to startup-disk-creator choose the image a click create.

Answer (score -1):

Seems a permission problem. I resolved a similar problem running usb-creator-gtk with sudo in a terminal:

```
sudo usb-creator-gtk
```